# Run function over columns with numeric values only in data table in r

Tags: r, data.table

I want to run the following function

```
count_greater_than <- function(x){
  ret <- sum(x > 1);
  return(ret);
}
```

over the iris data set as a data table. However, I only want to run the function for all the columns in iris with numeric values (all but 'Species'). My approach is

```
dt <- as.data.table(iris);
gr_1 <- dt[, sapply(.SD,count_greater_than, is.numeric)];
names(gr_1) <- colnames(iris);
gr_1;
```

Which gives me;

```
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
         150          150          149           93           NA
```

But wat I want is;

```
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
150          150          149           93
```

Is there a way to exclude the columns with non-numeric values? Or at least specify the columns I want to cover?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `.SDcols` to specify columns for which you want to apply the function.

```
library(data.table)
dt[, lapply(.SD, count_greater_than), .SDcols = sapply(dt, is.numeric)]


#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#1:          150         150          149          93
```

The equivalent in `dplyr` is :

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric), count_greater_than))
```

Comment: in development version 1.12.9: `.SDcols=is.numeric` now works; i.e., `SDcols=` accepts a function which is used to select the columns of `.SD`, see [here](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/news/index.html).

Comment: @Wimpel can you combine this syntax with "by"?

Comment: sure, i do not see why not.

Comment: The `dplyr`/`tidyverse` approach has now changed (`dplyr 1.0.0` or later, I think), to `dt %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric)), count_greater_than)` or just  `dt %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric)),  ~ sum (. > 1))`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use dplyr:

```
iris %>% 
   as_tibble() %>% 
   select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
   group_by(.) %>% 
   summarise_all(~ sum(. > 1))

# A tibble: 1 x 4
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
         <int>       <int>        <int>       <int>
1          150         150          149          93
```

Answer (score 0):

We can specify with `if/else` condition in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) count_greater_than(x) else NULL)]
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#1:          150         150          149          93
```